# Ubuntu 16.04 - Wifi Hotspot

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and until yesterday I had been using my laptop as a hotspot and was connecting my mobile to it. Today morning there had been some updates which I had updated.

When I came back in the evening and restarted the system I was unable to browse connecting my mobile to the hotspot. The mobile finds the hotspot but does not connect to it or displays the message no internet connection. I tried deleting the hotspot and creating another one but of no avail. The wired connection works perfectly well!!

Could anyone please guide me in the right direction of how to sort the issue.

Regards,
Raghav

Comment: Could you please try to boot into an older kernel and test if it works there? Some at least basic and better yet detailed info about the involved wireless adapter, their drivers and the exact access point set-up and configuration would help too. Thanks.